# I have a jsx button that should "flip" the data from one react component to another (siblings) that is not working for some reason

Tags: reactjs, button, state

I'm building a Currency Converter in React. I have two dropdowns, both contain a selection of currencies for the user to choose which currencies to convert.

I've included a "flip" button that I want to swap the currently selected currencies from both drop downs but I cannot get it to work.

Here is the parent component:

```
function App() {
  const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState("USD");
  const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = useState("EUR");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
  const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const currencyList = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP", "CAD", "MXN", "COP"];

  const handleFromCurrencyChange = (event) => {
    console.log("From currency changed to:", event.target.value);

    setFromCurrency(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleToCurrencyChange = (event) => {
    console.log("To currency changed to:", event.target.value);

    setToCurrency(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleAmountChange = (event) => {
    setAmount(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleFlip = () => {
   const currentFromCurrency = fromCurrency;
    const currentToCurrency = toCurrency;

    setFromCurrency(currentToCurrency);
    setToCurrency(currentFromCurrency);
    
    console.log("Flip");

  };

  
  return (
    <div className="wrapper flex flex-col items-center px-4 py-8">
    <div className="wrapper flex flex-col items-center px-4 py-8">
  <Header />

  <CurrencySelector
    currencyList={currencyList}
    fromCurrency={fromCurrency}
    toCurrency={toCurrency}
    handleFromCurrencyChange={handleFromCurrencyChange}
    handleToCurrencyChange={handleToCurrencyChange}
  />
  <HiOutlineSwitchHorizontal className="text-2xl text-blue-500 cursor-pointer mx-4 "
  onClick = {handleFlip}
   />

  <Input handleAmountChange={handleAmountChange} amount={amount} 
  
  />



  <ConvertButton className="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md mb-4" />
  <Result className="text-2xl font-bold" />
</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here are the currency selectors

```
const CurrencySelector = ({
  currencyList,
  fromCurrency,
  toCurrency,
  handleFromCurrencyChange,
  handleToCurrencyChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center mb-6">
      <FromCurrency
        currencyList={currencyList}
        onChange={handleFromCurrencyChange}
        className="mr-2"
        value={fromCurrency}
      />
      <ExchangeLogo />
      <ToCurrency
        currencyList={currencyList}
        onChange={handleToCurrencyChange}
        className="ml-2"
        value={toCurrency}
      />
    </div>
  );
};



const FromCurrency = ({ currencyList, onChange, className, value }) => {
  return (
    <select
      onChange={onChange}
      className={`border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-sm px-4 py-3 w-32 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300 mb-4 ${className}`}
    >
      {currencyList.map((currency) => (
        <option key={currency} value={currency}>
          {currency}
        </option>
      ))}
    
    </select>
  );
};

const ToCurrency = ({ currencyList, onChange, className, value }) => {
  return (
    <select
      onChange={onChange}
      className={`border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-sm px-4 py-3 w-32 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-300 mb-4 ${className}`}
    >
      {currencyList.map((currency) => (
        <option key={currency} value={currency}>
          {currency}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};
```

I included console logs on each currency dropdown, and the flip button itself. They confirmed that each component is correctly rendering its state to the console when selected. But my "handle Flip" function is not actually flipping the selected currencies. I think the issue has to be with the "handle flip" event handler or the logic in the dropdown components. I ran this through GPT 4 but was unable to receive a clear solution there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code needs to set the `value` property of the `<select>` elements, right now the the `value` prop passed into the `XCurrency` components is ignored:

```
const FromCurrency = ({ currencyList, onChange, className, value }) => {
  return (
    <select
      onChange={onChange}
      className={/* ... */}
      {/* ADD `value` prop! */}
      value={value}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </select>
  );
};

const ToCurrency = ({ currencyList, onChange, className, value }) => {
  return (
    <select
      onChange={onChange}
      className={/* ... */}
      {/* ADD `value` prop! */}
      value={value}
    >
      {/* ... */}
    </select>
  );
};
```